# Rails PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column carts_parts.[:part_id, :cart_id] does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, migration, join

so it seems I have yet again run into another problem with the associations in my join table. I have a join table CartsParts which is for a many-to-many relationship between Carts and Parts. The relation is a User has one cart and a Cart has many parts, but a Part has many and belongs to Carts since multiple users can have one cart. My join table has a cart_id and a part_id. After I set up the migrations I saw this error:

[image: Database error]

Here is my Part model

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items
  has_and_belongs_to_many :carts, through: :carts_parts
  has_many :carts_parts
```

Cart model

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :carts_parts 
  has_many :parts, through: :carts_parts
```

CartsPart model

```
class CartsPart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parts
  has_many :carts
  self.primary_key = [:part_id, :cart_id]
```

CartsPart table

```
 create_table "carts_parts", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "cart_id", null: false
    t.integer "part_id", null: false
  end
```

Carts Table

```
 create_table "carts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

and my Parts Table

```
create_table "parts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.text    "description"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.integer "price"
    t.boolean "active"
    t.integer "discount"
    t.string  "image"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.integer "carts_part_id"
  end
```

Thanks for any help to resolve this problem

Comment: Necessary to have both of these?    has_and_belongs_to_many :carts, through: :carts_parts    has_many :carts_parts   Within the Part model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing too much work. The `habtm` pattern relies greatly on convention. Even the order of names in the join table is important. So long as you [follow the conventions as described](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) then you don't need to define a `through` relationship, nor the primary key. Take those things out of your models and it should start working.